# Ways to get mutable strings from a Match object's chunks?

Tags: raku

I'm trying to map the chunks from a Match object to an array of Pairs with mutable string values -which I suppose requires scalarizing the strings. The only way I could figure out how to do this by putting them in square brackets and indexing them:

```
 my @n =map { $_.key => [$_.value.Str][0] }, G::parse($str).chunks;
```

Scalarizing with $(..) didn't work nor did cloning and such. There must be a more canonical way. And why didn't $(..) work -isn't that what it's for?

Comment: `$(…)` marks things as being an item (prevents flattening). Putting something in a scalar container also marks it as being an item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things to unpick here:

- All strings in P6 are immutable. (Thanks Liz. :)) But you probably don't mean you want to get a mutable string. You probably just mean having strings in containers so the contents of those containers can be changed.
- The `=>` pair constructor does not decontainerize its right hand value if it's in a container. So if `bar` is a `Scalar` container that contains a string then `foo => bar` constructs a pair with its value being that `Scalar` container containing that string.
- `$(...)` is used to parenthesize an expression that is to be treated as singular even if is a plural container. (This mirrors `@(...)` which is used to parenthesize an expression that is to be treated as plural even if it is a singular container or value.)
- It's not surprising that you thought `$(...)` would construct a `Scalar` container. (After all, `%(...)` constructs a `Hash`, so why not?) But instead you must use a `Scalar` declarator.
- The most succinct `Scalar` declarator is for an [anonymous state `Scalar`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#The_$_variable) using `$ = ...`. But @Håkon has used `my $ = ...` in their answer. Why? Because the `{...}` closure called by the `map` retains state between calls of it. If you use just `$ = ...` then you'd be reusing the same `Scalar` container for all the pairs. Instead you need `my $ = ...` to get fresh `Scalar`s for each pair's value.

Comment: "A string isn't immutable".  I'm afraid it is.  Perhaps you meant `s/isn't/is/`  ?

Answer (score 5):

You can put the immutable string into a scalar container by doing:

```
my @n = map { $_.key => my $ = $_.value.Str }, G::parse($str).chunks;
```

then you can later modify the content of the scalar container (but not the content of the string):

```
@n[0].value = "Hello";
```

Comment: You can also go fancy and create a prefix operator for that: `perl6 -e 'sub prefix:<§>(\a) is raw { my $ = a }; my $a := §42; $a = 666; say $a'  # 666`