# How do I mutate captures in a Grammar object?

Tags: grammar, raku

I'm trying to modify the values in a parsed Grammar object with this:

```
method mutate(Match:D $match --> Match:D) {
    for $match.values -> $line {
        when $line<content><header-toc><header><taskwiki-content><taskwiki-divider> {
            say 'here';
            $line<content><header-toc><header><taskwiki-content><taskwiki-divider>.replace-with('');
            say $line; # has not been modified;
        }
    };
    return $match;
}
```

I'm not getting any errors but the `$match` object is not affected by the `replace-with` method I'm running.

Comment: You have three statements inside the innermost block. The first one is `say 'here';`. What happens if you use `$_` topic variable in the second statement, a la `$_.replace-with('')`, and end the inner block there (try then moving the statement `say $line;` outside the innermost block)?

Comment: Get `No such method 'replace-with' for invocant of type 'Any'` error.

Comment: Tried `.replace-with('') with ...` does not throw errors but still, the `$match` object is unchanged.

Comment: You need an ` =` assignment somewhere, and my understanding is you'll be changing the $string, not the match object. Going to the docs , I can change the third line of the code to `$some-string = $match.replace-with("string");` and it works. See: https://docs.raku.org/routine/replace-with

Comment: So how do I modify the match object in a sane way?

Comment: Just trying to help. I try running `say $match.values` on the Docs code and I get back `()`, indicating a silent error. Maybe `Match` objects cannot be evaluated/coerced with routines like `kv`, `keys` or `values` ?

Answer (score 4):

> How do I mutate captures in a `Grammar` object?

You can't. (Well, you can hang data off them via `make`, but you can't do what you're thinking you can do.)

---

A `Match` object stores the result of a match against some string, and any captures are just `.from`, `.to` indexes into that original string.

For example, if you write `"bar".match(/a/)`, the resulting `Match` object stores the `.match` method's invocant `"bar"`, and has a `.from` of `1` and a `.to` of `2` which represents the captured `"a"` substring.

The original string remains immutable, and the captured substrings are "virtual" as it were, with nothing you can mutate.

---

> `foo.replace-with('');`

`replace-with` does not modify its invocant. It just returns a value (a new *string*).

Quoting [the `replace-with` doc](https://docs.raku.org/routine/replace-with), with my added **bold emphasis**:

> Returns the invocant **string** where the `Match` object is replaced by `$replacement`.

Note that it's *not* "the invocant **`Match` object**".

The `.replace-with` method is returning a new **string** that's a copy of the original *input* string that was matched *against* to produce the `Match` object, with the bit that was matched replaced by the string supplied as the `.replace-with` method's argument.

Comment: Shouldn't that read `$foo.replace-with('');`, with `$foo` representing a `Match` object as invocant? At least that's how I read the docs.

Comment: It can be `foo` or `$foo`, so long as it's a `Match` object.

Comment: Alright. So if I want to output two or more different versions of a parsed file, my only option is to parse the entire file each time and use different actions?

Comment: Just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778733/ways-to-get-mutable-strings-from-a-match-objects-chunks

Comment: @StevieD Nice answer! 

Comment: I think what I'm going to do is convert the match to an ordered hash.

Comment: As I've come to find out, converting a match object to a hash is not a trivial problem. Even if you did do it, you are going to have a very difficult time recreating the original string from it.